# css card flip effect, does not flip back

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and I'm working on getting some divs to do a card flip on the x-axis.  I've been able to do this successfully using some some basic html and css. The problem I'm running into is getting the card to flip back correctly. Currently when you take your mouse off of the box, it instantly reverts back to the front without the flip. 
In my research I've seen it noted that javascript/jquery is necessary to accomplish this, but then I've also seen examples where it works properly without any javascript/jquery. I'd prefer to learn it first without. So how can I get the divs to "flip back" properly?

jsfiddle code is here:  https://jsfiddle.net/pq4juLqz/1/

html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="flip-box">
            <div class="flip-front"><input type="button" value="test_front"></div>
            <div class="flip-back"><input type="button" value="test_back"></div>
        </div>
    </td>       
  </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.flip-box{perspective: 1000px;
      height: 30px;
      width: 100px;}
.flip-front,.flip-back{position: absolute;
                   top: 0px;
                   left: 0px;
                   height: 30px;
                   width:100px;
                   backface-visibility: hidden;}
.flip-front{z-index:2;
        transform: rotateY(0deg);}
.flip-back{transform: rotateY(180deg);}
.flip-box:hover{transition: 0.6s;
            position: relative;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform: rotateY(180deg);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the transition and transform-style property on flipbox and not flipbox:hover.

```
.flip-box{transition: 0.6s;
        position: relative;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        }

.flip-box:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

try changing the last few lines to this and it'll work.
Updated JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pq4juLqz/5/

Comment: That did it. Thank-you for explaining what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```css
p{
width:100%;
height:100%;
text-align:center;
margin-top:35%;
font:400 22px helvetica;
color:White;
}
.flip{ width:240px; height:200px; margin:10px; border-radius:20px;}

.flip > .front{
 position:absolute;
 transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
 background:#151718; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 12px;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 transition: transform .6s linear 0s;
}
.flip > .back{
 position:absolute;
 transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
 background: skyblue; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 12px;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 transition: transform .6s linear 0s;
}
.flip:hover > .front{
 transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
}
.flip:hover > .back{
 transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
}
```

```html
<div class="flip">
  <div class="back"><p>HTML</center></p></div>
  <div class="front"><p>PHP</p></div>
</div>
```

See Demo - [Flip box](http://lamina17.info/code/tool/flip.html).
For more [Html css web codes](http://lamina17.info/web_tech)

Answer (score 0):

*Here it is, but I can tell that it get's buggy. So I assume that's where `JS` kicks in.*

**HTML**

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flip-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn-flip front">Flip Front</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-flip back">Flip Back</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flip-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;

    -ms-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);

    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-buttons,
.flip-buttons > .btn-flip {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

.flip-buttons {
    position: relative;

    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    transition: 0.6s;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-buttons > .btn-flip {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 2px solid #3cf;
    background-color: #39d;
    color: #fafafa;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    transition: 0.6s;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.flip-buttons > .btn-flip.front {
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.flip-buttons:hover > .btn-flip.front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-buttons > .btn-flip.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip-buttons:hover > .btn-flip.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

[Flippy Buttons JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvLden/pq4juLqz/3/)

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, it doesn't really tell me what was wrong with the code I already had.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem when adding a style rule to a *hover* state of an element when transforming with *transition*: The element might completely get invisible for a moment, when it is being rotated by 90 degrees. Now you are adding a style rule for the "hovered" state to that component...

The solution is to wrap the rotated div and add add a style rule to the rotated div **when** hovering the wrapper div:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="hover-listener-wrapper">
                <div class="flip-box">
                    <div class="flip-front"><input type="button" value="test_front"></div>
                    <div class="flip-back"><input type="button" value="test_back"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>       
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.flip-box{
    perspective: 1000px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flip-box:hover{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-front,.flip-back{position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    width:100px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flip-front{
    z-index:2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flip-back{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pkkmdp2/)